# System.TypeInitializationException in Uwp using mvvm?

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

ResourceDictionary:

```
<locator:ConstructionLocator x:Key="Construction"/>
```

addEngineerView.xaml

```
<Page DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Construction}, Path=AddEngineerViewModel}"/>
```

Locator:

```
public class ConstructionLocator
{

    private static IDialogServices _dialog = new DialogServices();
    private static IAddEngineerDataService _addEngineerDataServices = new AddEngineerDataServices(new AddEngineerData());

    private static AddEngineerViewModel _addEngineerViewModel = new AddEngineerViewModel(_addEngineerDataServices, _dialog);
    private static ViewEmployeeViewModel _viewEmployeeViewModel = new ViewEmployeeViewModel(_addEngineerDataServices, _dialog);


    public static AddEngineerViewModel AddEngineerViewModel
    {
        get { return _addEngineerViewModel; }
    }

    public static ViewEmployeeViewModel ViewEmployeeViewModel
    {
        get { return _viewEmployeeViewModel; }
    }

}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class AddEngineerViewModel:BindableBase
{
    IAddEngineerDataService _engineerDataService;
    IDialogServices _dialog;

    public AddEngineerViewModel(IAddEngineerDataService AddEngineerDataService,IDialogServices Dialog)
    {
        _engineerDataService = AddEngineerDataService;
        _dialog = Dialog;
        LoadCommand();
    }

    private AddEngineerModel _addEngineer;
    public AddEngineerModel AddEngineer
    {
        get { return _addEngineer; }
        set
        {
            _addEngineer = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("AddEngineer");
        }
    }

    public ICommand AddEngineerCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand ViewEngineerCommand { get; set; }

    private void LoadCommand()
    {
        AddEngineerCommand = new CustomCommand(Add, CanAdd);
        ViewEngineerCommand = new CustomCommand(Views, CanView);
    }

    private void Views(object obj)
    {
        _dialog.ShowDialog();
    }

    private bool CanView(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private bool CanAdd(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void Add(object obj)
    {
        _engineerDataService.Add_Engineer_Details(_addEngineer);
    }
}
```

When navigate to view on button click it shows Type initializer threw exception in locator file of addengineerviewmodel static property. Above are my locator and viewmodel. what would be the problem?

Comment: Where are you using ConstructionLocator? Could you provide a [complete minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Edited my question can you understand now? I am using Constructionlocator in resourcedictionary and set the datacontext as mentioned above in the view

Comment: You need to catch the exception, call ToString on it, and save it.  It should tell you exactly where the problem is, if not exactly what it is.

Comment: But i couldn't catch the exception in the Constructionlocator class. So where should i catch it?